# Cloud Firestore rules only allow author to read document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following document

[image: The firesotre document]

and I have set the following rules

[image: The firestore rules]

Every time I try to read the document using the Android SDK

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("users").get().addOnCompleteListener(appExecutors
                     .networkIO(),
             task -> {});
```

I am getting this error

> "com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions."

I am not sure what is wrong is it the rules or the Android call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had to add a where close in my code

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("authorId",user.getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(appExecutors.networkIO(),task -> {});
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you meant to type `resource.data.author_id` instead of `resource.data.author_d` in the rule.

Comment: Thank you, but I guess there that was not the issue. This was just a sample code. the original one did not have this typo

Answer (score 0):

This code is trying to access every document in the entire users collection:

```
db.collection("users").get()
```

If there any any document in that collection that violates the security rules you set up, then it will fail.

Did you instead intend to try to access the single document that the user is supposed to have access to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this from firebase consol. You just need to sllow access to all user. As I remember by default there was allowed only authorized users.